# Paypal purchase form won't navigate to Paypal

Tags: php, iframe, paypal, transactions, paypal-sandbox

I'm using [gpixpixel](http://www.tufat.com/script63.htm) script, and configured it to allow the visitor to buy pixels via Paypal, but upon clicking the "Pay with Paypal" button, the page only shows a DNS error.

Here's the code of the form on the page for a transaction:

```
<form method="post" action="https://sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr">
<input type="hidden" name="amount" value="1620">
<input type="hidden" name="business" value="testmerchant@nodomain.com">
<input type="hidden" name="cancel_return" value="http://-site-/gpix/get_pixels.php?step=6">
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick">
<input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="USD">
<input type="hidden" name="custom" value="8:c6f79ef0f714fae081a6df9d778df198">
<input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="Pixels: ">
<input type="hidden" name="no_note" value="1">
<input type="hidden" name="NotifyURL" value="http://-site-/gpix/paypal_ipn.php?payment_id=8">
<input type="hidden" name="no_shipping" value="1">
<input type="hidden" name="return" value="http://-site-/gpix/index.php">
<input type="hidden" name="rm" value="2">
<p>
  <input type="submit" value="Pay with PayPal >>">
</p>
</form>
```

Also, this page is opened in an iframe within another page (located in the same directory.)

Any help is appreciated.

I can post the link to the website if anyone wants to look at the installation.

Answer (score 0):

[image]You are missing `www`

Try:

`<form method="post" action="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr">`

Comment: Thanks. Now it doesn't throw a DNS error, but tries to load the page, the status bar says waiting for sandbox.paypal.com, and then it stops. **Still not navigating to Paypal.**

Comment: it did work for me, probably something wrong with ur network.screenshot added

Comment: Here is the link to [the installation](http://chetansharma.info/gpix). Can't figure out why this is not working.

Comment: It's the iframe's same origin policy that's restricting it! Stupid me.

Comment: glad u figured your problem

Answer (score 0):

It was the browser's same origin policy that was restricting the page, which I had embedded as an iframe within another page, from navigating to Paypal's website.

Thanks to Vimal for pointing out the missing www, whose omission created a wrong URL, and obviously wouldn't navigate anywhere.